# How to show some panel in Collapsed component? ExtJs 3.4

Tags: extjs

How to create something like:

```
var simple = Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: 'form',
    collapsible: true,
    frame: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
    }]
});
```

but when i click on collapse button stay visible?
Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you not want the user to be able to collapse the form? In that case, just set collapsible to false.

Comment: :) no no User can collapse form but can't collapse button. But the form and button must be on one panel

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to make this kind of behavior when panel is collapsed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNoEi.png)

an when it is expanded to show it with text and the icons align left to the text.